# Backbone.js - Collection keeps getting reset after fetch.success gets called

Tags: backbone.js

I have existing items in a collection and I want to call fetch with a different url to bring in other items that will be merged in.

For some reason reset is being called even if I use the reset:false flag and I think it has something to do with my success callback.

Is there anyway to disable the reset event and still use the success callback?

My fetch looks like this:

```
self.collection.fetch({
   url: url,
   add: true,
   reset: false,
   success: function() {
     self.render();
     $('.loading').hide();
   },
   error: function() { 
     $('.loading').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: There is no issue using success and reset false, also reset is set false by default(NOTE: I'm assuming you have Backbone.js 1.0.0 because previous versions always fired reset)

Comment: Yes, I do have the 1.0.0 version. What can I do to solve this problem aside from manually merging the collection after fetch?

Comment: As far as I see set reset to false won't prevent `reset` event from being triggered, http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: I had that problem before, and what I did was to use two collections instead of one, `fetch` from newer then `add` elements to the first, what do you think?

Comment: OK, I guess my only option is to copy the existing items and add them back to the collection after I call fetch. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have already faced this problem and solved like this. You can also try this

```
self.collection.fetch({
   url: url,
   add: true,
   add: true,
   remove: false,
   update: true,
   success: function() {
     self.render();
     $('.loading').hide();
   },
   error: function() { 
     $('.loading').hide();
   }
});
```